# pymongo : find query with regex

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am working on a python script to connect to mongodb and query a collection.

I want to find the values for key `hp` that start with `cdl`. This query successfully runs when I try through mongo shell but through my python script I see the error.

Do I need to have any escape characters ?

```
./pymongoconn.py

File "./pymongoconn.py", line 20

for response in conn.collection.find({"hp": /^cdl/},{"n":1 ,"hp":1 , "_id":0 , "rsid" :1, "v":1}):                                         

^   

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Below is my query :

```py
for response in conn.collection.find(
    {"hp": /^cdl/},
    {"n":1 ,"hp":1 , "_id":0 ,"rsid" :1, "v":1}
):
    print (response)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use re.compile:

```
import re
cdl= re.compile("^cdl", re.IGNORECASE)
for response in conn.collection.find(
  {"hp": cdl},
  {"n":1 ,"hp":1 , "_id":0 ,"rsid" :1, "v":1}
):
  print (response)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your syntax is slightly wrong for a `$regex` in pymongo.

Try:

```
 conn.collection.find(
   {"hp": {"$regex": "^cdl"}}, 
   {"n":1 ,"hp":1 , "_id":0 ,"rsid" :1, "v":1}
 )
```

You could also add in `$option` into the `$regex`. If you wanted case insensitive;

```
conn.collection.find({"hp": {"$regex": "^cdl", "$options": "i"}}))
```

You have all the options available as per mongo `$regex`, [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/)